# Put an ajax in a for statement in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, for-loop

I want to call jquery ajax in a php for loop statement. my code is like:

```
 for(i=0;i<selectedStudents.length;i++){
                   console.log(selectedStudents[i]);
                    var userId=selectedStudents[i][13];
                  console.log(userId);
                   console.log(i);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://10.10.212.50:8080/.../member/add",
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: '{"requester": { "userName": "' + AdminUsername + '", "password": "' + AdminPass + '" },"request":{"taskId": ' + taskId + ',"userId":' + userId + '}  }',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (GetResult) {
                             console.log(GetResult);

                            if (GetResult.result) {
                                swal("تمام", "افزودن کاربر به گروه کاری، با موفقیت انجام شد!!.", "success")

                                console.log(i);
                                console.log(selectedStudents);

                                var memberString='<li style="background-color: #39CCCC;border-color: #0c0c0c; " class="list-group-item row">'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<h4 class="col-md-9" style=" text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">'+selectedStudents[i][1]+'" " '+selectedStudents[i][2]+'</h4>'+

                                        '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                                        '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+selectedStudents[i][0]+'">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input id="'+userId+'firstName" type="text" style="display:none" value="'+selectedStudents[i][1]+'">'+
               '</div>'+
                                        ' </li>';
                                $("#"+taskId+"hiddenMemberLI").after(memberString);

                            } else {
                                sweetAlert("خطا", "افزودن کاربر به گروه کاری، با مشکل رو به رو شده است!!", "error");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    })//end ajax
                }//end for
```

When i see result of console.log()s, i see first all for loop, then ajax run. this mean when code want to run for example `selectedStudents[i][0]` i is out of range.

I must call ajax , one bye one. 
How must i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $.ajax with async: false option

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://10.10.212.50:8080/.../member/add",
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: '{"requester": { "userName": "' + AdminUsername + '", "password": "' + AdminPass + '" },"request":{"taskId": ' + taskId + ',"userId":' + userId + '}  }',
   dataType: "json",
   async: false,
   success: function (GetResult) {  
       //your logic
   }
});
```

Comment: Never use `async: false`. It is evil.

Comment: Yes, but as per @narges need I have suggest this

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is an asynchronous operation, because it doesn't know when your server will respond to the request. That's why it returns a promise, which needs to be handled in the code.

For loop simultaneously fires n AJAX requests and completes, and doesn't wait for the requests to get completed. If you want to run the requests one by one, do that in `success` callback, or more efficiently, implement a `.done` promise handler.